# Eliminar elementos de un array en C#

Tags: c#, array

Buenas tengo el siguiente código:

```
if (nombre==null){
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("No hay contactos almacenados aún");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("¿Qué contacto desea eliminar?");
    string busqueda = Console.ReadLine();
    for(int i=0;i<nombre.Length;i++){   
        if (busqueda==nombre[i]){ 
            nombre[i]=null;
            telefono[i]=null;
            email[i]=null;
            direccion[i]=null;
        }
    }
```

Estoy creando un registro y mientras no haya insertado los datos para el array (es decir, mientras lo tenga en null) no quiero que abra la función de borrar los datos, pero cuando la abre y ejecuta la búsqueda, al poner cada posición del array en null, no elimina mis elementos.

(Estos array los tengo como variable global y al insertarlos en una función posterior tienen el mismo límite de elementos).

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/):

Primero agregas la directiva:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Luego buscas el indice en el array `nombre` que coincida con la variable `busqueda` .

```
int indexEnNombreABorrar = nombre.ToList().FindIndex(n => n == busqueda);
```

Luego teniendo este indice lo usas para que lo excluya del nuevo array usando la query `Where` de Linq y lo asigne nuevamente a tu array `nombre`.

```
nombre = nombre.Where(n => n != nombre[indexEnNombreABorrar]).ToArray();
```

Y tendrías que hacer lo mismo con `telefono, email y dirección.`

Comment: Gracias, me ha dado una idea.

Answer (score 1):

Poner cada posición de un array en null, no es lo mismo que el array sea = null.

Tene en cuenta, que la variable que guarda el array es la que estas comparando con null al hacer `nombre==null`, pero al hacer `nombre[i]=null` no quiere decir que el array completo apunta a null.

Cuando hiciste `nombre[i]=null`, lo que es null es la posicion i de ese array. Pero tu array, sigue teniendo valores. y en este caso, tiene un monton de posiciones con valores null.

No mostras como creas cada posicion del array, pero lo que tendrias que hacer es "reducir" su tamaño, hasta que llegue a 0 y ahi si podrias compararlo con null. O escribir una funcion, que verifique si todas las posiciones del array son null, y ahi decidir que no tiene datos.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

si deseas borrar todos los valores de un array sin conocer el index podrias hacer algo asi:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 4, 9, 2 };
int numToRemove = 4;
numbers = numbers.Where(val => val != numToRemove).ToArray();
```

**es solo un ejemplo**

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp/497005)